# Beautiful soup and bottlenose, how to parse correctly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, bottlenose

I am currently trying to extract strings from the response of a bottlenose amazon api request. 
Without wanting to cause [Russian hackers to pwn to my webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I am trying to use beautiful soup following [this small webpage as guide.](http://pythonprojectwatch.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/making-new-amazon-product-api-easy-to.html)

My current code:

```
import bottlenose as BN
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

amazon = BN.Amazon('MyAmznID','MyAmznSK','MyAmznAssTag',Region='UK', Parser=BeautifulSoup)
rank = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="0198596790",ResponseGroup="SalesRank")

soup = BeautifulSoup(rank)

print rank
print soup.find('SalesRank').string
```

This is the current output from bottlenose looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><html><body><itemlookupresponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"><operationrequest><httpheaders><header name="UserAgent" value="Python-urllib/2.7"></header></httpheaders><requestid>53f15ff4-3588-4e63-af6f-279bddc7c243</requestid><arguments><argument name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="################"></argument><argument name="AssociateTag" value="#########-##"></argument><argument name="ItemId" value="0198596790"></argument><argument name="Operation" value="ItemLookup"></argument><argument name="ResponseGroup" value="SalesRank"></argument><argument name="Service" value="AWSECommerceService"></argument><argument name="Timestamp" value="2016-02-04T11:05:48Z"></argument><argument name="Version" value="2011-08-01"></argument><argument name="Signature" value="################+##################="></argument></arguments><requestprocessingtime>0.0234130000000000</requestprocessingtime></operationrequest><items><request><isvalid>True</isvalid><itemlookuprequest><idtype>ASIN</idtype><itemid>0198596790</itemid><responsegroup>SalesRank</responsegroup><variationpage>All</variationpage></itemlookuprequest></request><item><asin>0198596790</asin><salesrank>124435</salesrank></item></items></itemlookupresponse></body></html>
```

So the bottle nose section works but the soup section gives an error response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Fuck/Documents/Amazon/Bottlenose_amzn_prog/test.py", line 12, in <module>
print soup.find(Rank).string
NameError: name 'soup' is not defined
```

I am trying to extract the digits between the 'SalesRank' tags, but failing.

Comment: And what if `BeautifulSoup.soup`?

Comment: do you mean >soup = BeautifulSoup.soup(rank), if so no. This gives Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Documents/Amazon/Bottlenose_amzn_prog/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup.soup(rank)
AttributeError: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'soup'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at [the code](https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose/blob/master/bottlenose/api.py), it seems that the Bottlenose `Parser` option is very simple and takes a function as the parameter.

So you can just make a very simple Python function and pass it to the constructor, which makes your code look like this:

```
import bottlenose as BN
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_xml(text):
    return BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')

amazon = BN.Amazon(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG,Region='UK', Parser=parse_xml
)
results = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="0198596790",ResponseGroup="SalesRank")

print results.find('SalesRank').string
```

Or you can use a lambda in-line function instead:

```
import bottlenose as BN
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

amazon = BN.Amazon(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG,
    Region='UK', Parser=lambda text: BeautifulSoup(text, 'xml')
)
results = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="0198596790",ResponseGroup="SalesRank")

print results.find('SalesRank').string
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have ignored the option to specify parser in the bottlenose line. 
Instead just specifying to use BeautifulSoup and xml parsing later.

```
import bottlenose as BN
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

amazon = BN.Amazon('##############','##############','##########',Region='UK')
rank = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="specifiedItemId",ResponseGroup="SalesRank")
soup = BeautifulSoup(rank, "xml")
print " " 
print soup.SalesRank
```

I am a fairly novice user of Python so sometimes its the simple things that get me.